# updating a progress bar while writing an Excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Given code that writes a substential amount of data to an excel file using Apache POI:

```
var workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook()
addSubstentialAmountOfDataToWorkbook(workbook)
workbook.write(outputStream) // might take a few minutes and need to update the progress bar
workbook.close()
```

and a progress bar that can be updated with `progressBar.add(10) // add 10% to the progress`

How can one update a progress bar while writing a very big Excel file using Apache POI?

My initial thoughts were to look at the size of the xlsx file while it is being written in some asynchronous way but it seem to add a lot of clutter to the code.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workbook writing use always the same amout of time you might do it. Otherwise, I would suggest a simple spinner (for example [here](https://loading.io/css/)) instead of a progressbar. Because you don't know how long it will take to generate your file. You can't determinate what is the "100%" and how long to achieve it.